# Help with the Mann–Whitney U test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, nonparametric

I am new to statistics and really struggling here. I would appreciate any help that I could get.  I am supposed to use a non-parametric test (Mann-Whitney U test was suggested) to check the difference in protein concentration of serum and plasma. I have 8 samples of each. Each plasma sample is related to a serum sample (they come from the same patient). I need a statistical analysis of the difference between plasma and serum samples and then to check if there is a statistical significance.

**The hypothesis is as follows: to check if the protein concentration in serum is lower than the protein concentration in plasma.**

I'm trying to use SPSS to do the Mann-Whitney test but I'm not sure if I entered and marked the variables correctly. Don't know if Im supposed to even have patient numbers. I have checked tons of youtube tutorials but none of them can I correlate to my data.

[image: SPSS values that I entered]

Comment: This test would be a poor choice for your data, because they are *paired.*  At bottom, statistics is common sense supported by mathematics and logic. The first thing you can and should do, then, is inspect your data to check for consistency with the hypothesis: how often is the serum concentration lower than the plasma concentration?  By how much?  In your case, the answers are clear and easily found. If someone naively insists that you produce a p-value or other statement of "significance," then use a [sign test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_test).

Comment: I’ve calculated the average for Plasma as 85.25 and for Serum as 82.97. No test is going to reject a null hypothesis that plasma has the lower average. Further, it appears you have paired data (one measurement of plasma and one measurement of serum per patient...the same patient). Mann-Whitney does not account for the pairing. Who told you to run that test?

Comment: @Dave How is comparing the arithmetic means relevant to the question about *non-parametric* testing? Moreover, the lower serum mean actually is consistent with the hypothesis, so it's difficult to see how to justify your "no test" statement. If we invert the hypothesis, it's still possible for seven of the eight differences to have a sign opposite the difference of means, which would reject the null at $p=9/256=3.5\%.$ Finally, the issue of "who told you" is irrelevant and could be misinterpreted as sounding belligerent rather than helpful.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the reply. I did use the sing test as you suggested and I got that the result is not significant at p < .05   Is this the right answer? I did get four +1s and four -1s.  But I'm still a bit unsure.

Comment: What does your common sense tell you when half the results go one way and half go the other?  Indeed, is it possible to get a result that is any more balanced than that?

Comment: @whuber Oh I understand now. Thank you so much!